# Overwrite create method for a Django restframework nested serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use nested writable serializer in django-rest-framework. When I send a POST request with following data:

```
{
    "acc_name": "Salary Card",
    "acc_type_id": {
        "id": 2,
        "acc_type_name": "Debit Card"
    },
    "credit_amt": null,
    "bill_dt": null,
    "due_dt": null,
    "balance": "0.00",
    "comments": null
}
```

I got an error:

```
Cannot assign "OrderedDict([('acc_type_name', 'Debit Card')])": "Accounts.acc_type_id" must be a "AccountTypes" instance.
```

I actually passed id for AccountTypes, but why restframework remove it automatically? How can I resolve this problem? How can I create a new account with existing account type?

**Views:**

```py
class AccountTypesViewSet(ListAPIView):
    name = __name__
    pagination_class = None
    queryset = AccountTypes.objects.filter(active='Y')
    serializer_class = AccountTypesSerializer


class AccountsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = None
    queryset = Accounts.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountsSerializer
```

**Models:**

```py
class AccountTypes(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    acc_type_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='Y')

    class Meta:
        db_table = f'"{schema}"."taccount_types"'
        managed = False

class Accounts(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    acc_name = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    acc_type_id = models.ForeignKey(
        to=AccountTypes,
        db_column='acc_type_id',
        related_name='accounts',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
    )
    credit_amt = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    bill_dt = models.DateField(null=True)
    due_dt = models.DateField(null=True)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = f'"{schema}"."taccounts"'
        managed = False
```

**Serializers:**

```py
class AccountTypesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AccountTypes
        fields = ('id', 'acc_type_name')


class AccountsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # acc_type = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='acc_type_name', source='acc_type_id', read_only=True)
    acc_type_id = AccountTypesSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Accounts
        fields = ('id', 'acc_name', 'acc_type_id', 'credit_amt',
                  'bill_dt', 'due_dt', 'balance', 'comments')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        accounts_instance = Accounts.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return accounts_instance
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `id` field because Django will do it by itself, so remove that lines:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

Next, you need to send an `id` of `AccountTypes` model to create new account and you give Django a dict `fields = ('id', 'acc_type_name')`. It doesn't know what to do with that. So just send `id` as number. And you don't need `AccountTypesSerializer` and that line `acc_type_id = AccountTypesSerializer()` also.

Next, you should create account in view, not in serializer, and you have to save it after creating.